# How do I use setters from a RecyclerView adapter within a Runnable object?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, runnable

I want to preface this by saying I'm new to Android. In my project, I have a stopwatch running on a `Runnable` object and a `RecyclerView` containing buttons which the user can use to get the time on the stopwatch at that instant.

I need a way to somehow get `long currentCentiseconds` from my main activity to my `RecyclerViewAdapter`. So far, I've tried to use setters to constantly update a variable in my `RecylerViewAdapter`, but because I am calling it from another thread, it prevents the buttons from being pressed.

Is there any way around this problem?

Main activity:

```
public class Timer extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button startBtn;
private RecyclerView swimmerRecview;
private TextView txtTimer;
private Handler handler;
private int minutes, seconds, centiseconds = 0;
private SwimmerRecViewAdapter adapter;

private Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted(
        new Ticker() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            @Override
            public long read() {
                return android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
            }
        }
);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    ArrayList<Swimmer> swimmers = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("SWIMMERS");

    swimmerRecview = findViewById(R.id.swimmerRecView);
    adapter = new SwimmerRecViewAdapter(this, 2);
    adapter.setSwimmers(swimmers);

    swimmerRecview.setAdapter(adapter);
    swimmerRecview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    txtTimer =  findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
    handler = new Handler();

    startBtn = findViewById(R.id.actionBtn);
    startBtn.setText("Start Timer");
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (startBtn.getText().toString().equals("Start Timer")) { //start
            startBtn.setText("Stop Timer");
            stopwatch.start();
            handler.post(runnable);
        }
        else if (startBtn.getText().toString().equals("Stop Timer")) { //stop
            startBtn.setText("Reset Timer");
            stopwatch.stop();
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        else {
            startBtn.setText("Next");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Timer.this, SwimmerDetails.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("SWIMMERS", swimmers);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long currentCentiseconds = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) / 10;
        adapter.setCurrentTimer(currentCentiseconds);

        seconds = (int) (currentCentiseconds / 100);
        minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        centiseconds =  (int) (currentCentiseconds % 100);

        txtTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%02d.%02d", minutes,seconds,centiseconds));
        
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10);
    }
};
```

Here is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class SwimmerRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private static ArrayList<Swimmer> swimmers = new ArrayList<>();
private int type;
private Context context;
private long currentCentiseconds = 0;
private Handler handler;

public SwimmerRecViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutType) {
    type = layoutType;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return swimmers.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return type;
}

public void setSwimmers(ArrayList<Swimmer> swimmers) {
    this.swimmers = swimmers;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setCurrentTimer(long currentCentiseconds) {
    this.currentCentiseconds = currentCentiseconds;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ...
    else if (viewType == 2) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swimmer_list_item2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder2(view, viewType);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
    ...
    else if (holder instanceof ViewHolder2) { //Timer
        ((ViewHolder2) holder).txtName.setText(swimmers.get(position).getName());
        ((ViewHolder2) holder).txtlaneNumber.setText(position + 1 + "");

        ((ViewHolder2) holder).splitBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + currentCentiseconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (currentCentiseconds != 0) {
                swimmers.get(position).addLaps(currentCentiseconds);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView txtlaneNumber;
    private TextView txtName;
    private Button splitBtn;

    public ViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        txtlaneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtlaneNumber);
        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        splitBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.splitBtn);
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself:

First, I needed to use an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) to make it thread-safe because I was updating it in another thread (`Runnable`).

To continuously update the variable within the `RecyclerViewAdapter`, I used a `custom interface` containing the AtomicLong declaration which I implemented in my adapter and main activity. Thus, when I updated the `AtomicLong currentCentiseconds` in my `Runnable`, it also updated the variable within my `adapter class`, which I could then use myself.